# TFS 2012: How to build a custom build .xaml file?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

How to customize .xaml file in such a way that, whenever a developer does a gated-check-in,
only checked-in files will be copied to a pre-determined path/folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identify the changeset that triggered the build. Look inside the changeset to identify the files that were checked in, copy this list of files to where you want them to go.

you may have to write a custom activity to do this in one activity.